# why do 'data=data.dropna()' and 'data.dropna(inplace=True)' generate different results?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compare the returns of simple moving averages strategy with original returns following the textbook code. The only difference lies in the treatment of N/A data and the results are completely different.

According to the definition of `df.dropna(inplace=True)`, it keeps the DataFrame with valid entries in the same variable, which should be equal to `df=df.dropna()`. But results are different, why?

**1.textbook treatment:**

```
    data=pd.DataFrame(data)

    data['SMA1'] = data['Close'].rolling(42).mean()
    data['SMA2'] = data['Close'].rolling(252).mean()

    data['Position'] = np.where(data['SMA1'] > data['SMA2'], 1, -1)
    data['Returns'] = np.log(data['Close'] / data['Close'].shift(1))
    data['Strategy'] = data['Position'].shift(1) * data['Returns']
    data.dropna(inplace=True)

    np.exp(data[['Returns', 'Strategy']].sum())

#output 1
#Returns     4.017144
#Strategy    5.811294
```

**2.my treatment**

```
    data=pd.DataFrame(data)
    data['SMA1'] = data['Close'].rolling(42).mean()
    data['SMA2'] = data['Close'].rolling(252).mean()

    data['Position'] = np.where(data['SMA1'] > data['SMA2'], 1, -1)
    data['Returns'] = np.log(data['Close'] / data['Close'].shift(1))
    data['Strategy'] = data['Position'].shift(1) * data['Returns']
    data=data.dropna()

    np.exp(data[['Returns', 'Strategy']].sum())

#output 2
#Returns     3.199432
#Strategy    4.628373
```

Comment: This is strange. Can you share the data? Or you can try checking `data.shape` and content of `data` in both methods. May be from that you can figure out something.

Comment: If you're running them one after the other `data = pd.DataFrame(data)` **does not re-initialize** the DataFrame in treatment 2.  It copies it from where you left off (the end of the previous calculation) so these calculations aren't starting from the same point.

Comment: Like someone else said, restart the kernel and run them separately. They are supposed to return the same result.

Comment: Thank you all, you have solved my problem! The results do look different after each operation because of the change of data shape. I thought the second 'data' in the code `data = pd.DataFrame(data)` would have referred to the original panda series.

Comment: @RochelleWang nope, because `data` becomes your DataFrame, which you then modify, and pandas has no issues constructing a DataFrame from a DataFrame (which is why it goes unnoticed later). I'd just name your DataFrames `df` instead of data.

Comment: @ALollz Oh I see. Thank you a lot for clarification and sharing your experience!